# Is HTTPS TLS or SSL?

Tags: ssl, https

How to know a HTTPS connection in use is TLS-based or SSL-based?

If I want to use TLS instead of SSL in Apache2, is there anything special to config?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does it matter? TLS can be considered just a newer version of SSL, and SSLv3 is still secure and used.

"HTTPS" doesn't imply any version. By default, Apache's [`mod_ssl`](http://www.modssl.org/) accepts all protocol versions, and most clients pick the newest supported one. You can change it using the [`SSLProtocol`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslprotocol) directive - [most recent browsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Browser_implementations) support at least TLS v1.0.

(It would be helpful if you updated your question with *why* do you want TLS in particular.)